# SQL Statement Sum with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following structure(it cannot change) with composite primary key

```
Key1 (composite primary key)
Key2 (composite primary key)
Key3 (composite primary key)
Code (also part of Primary Key)
Amount
Active
```

User enters Codes for each Key1,Key2, Key3, Code and amounts. There are 3 codes for which user makes an entry. I can easily group them together to display sum of amount of each Code, key1,key2 and key3.

```
SELECT     SUM(Amount) AS sum
FROM         Table
GROUP BY Key1, Key2, Key3, Code
```

However, I have to write a SQL to display result like this

```
Key1 Key2 Key3 SumoofAmountsfCode1 SumoofAmountsfCode2 SumoofAmountsfCode3
```

Comment: Are you looking for [pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: You can do [conditional aggregation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/310674/Conditional-Sums-in-SQL-Aggregate-Methods).

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways of doing it:

```
SELECT 
   Key1, 
   Key2, 
   Key3, 
   sum(case when code = 1 then Amount else 0 end) SumoofAmountsfCode1,
   sum(case when code = 2 then Amount else 0 end) SumoofAmountsfCode2,
   sum(case when code = 3 then Amount else 0 end) SumoofAmountsfCode3
from Table
group by Key1, Key2, Key3
```

Or using `PIVOT`

```
SELECT 
   Key1, 
   Key2, 
   Key3, 
   IsNull([1],0) SumoofAmountsfCode1,
   IsNull([2],0) SumoofAmountsfCode2,
   IsNull([3],0) SumoofAmountsfCode3
from Table A
pivot (sum(amount) for code in ([1],[2],[3])) B
```